# Web2py update 1 record

Tags: web2py

I'm using SQLFORM.grid with the added selectable to select records.

```
form = SQLFORM.grid(query=query, fields=fields, headers=headers, 
    orderby=default_sort_order, create=False, deletable=False, editable=True, 
    maxtextlength=64, user_signature=False, paginate=25, csv=False, 
    selectable=lambda ids: [copy_itemNumbers(ids)])
```

Selected rows's ids will be passed as a list to the function:

```
def copy_itemNumbers(ids):
   for row in ids:
        db(db.items.id==int(row)).update(isMoved=1)
```

I want to update each record one by one and have the boolean isMoved set to 1.
It seems to run through but the update never realizes into the DB.  I tried the update_record approach with no luck or with just errors...

What am i missing?

Thanks!

John

UPDATE:

Below is my define table

```
db.define_table('items', 
                    Field('itemNumber', 'id'),
                    Field('price', 'integer'),             
                    Field('numSold', 'integer'),   
                    Field('imageName', 'string'),             
                    Field('isMoved', 'boolean'),
                    )
```

Comment: Your exact code works for me. Is this part of a regular HTTP request? If not, you need to do `db.commit()`. Is any error returned? Is the grid loaded via Ajax (possibly in a web2py component)? We may need to see more complete code.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to loop through each record. Just do `db(db.items.id.belongs(ids)).update(isMoved=1)` to update all records at once. Also, not sure why you defined `selectable` as a lambda with `copy_itemNumbers(ids)` in a list. You can just do `selectable=copy_itemNumbers`.

Comment: no error whatsoever. I can confirm it executes through it too. I tried adding db.commit() but it still didn't show up on the database.

Comment: So!!! I tested it by changing the field that it updates. I had it update another field, "price" and it actually updated it.  So why is the isMoved not updating?

Comment: Another find, i updated the "isMoved" to 1 manually on the database itself.  I then ran through the SQLFORM form and it shows as not checked.  I then tried checking it and submitting it.  Afterwards, it's still show unchecked. 
I did the same test, editing and stuff on other fields and it reflects fine.   

On my database structure: isMoved is a tinyint(1) Null = Yes Default = Null

Comment: I changed the structure to Null = No and Default = 0.  Tried it but still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

After searching the interWeb, i found that web2py treats boolean as boolean while mysql treats it as tinyin(1)

So, add this to the model

```
import copy
```

then

```
db._adapter.types = copy.copy(db._adapter.types)
db._adapter.types['boolean']='TINYINT(1)'
db._adapter.TRUE = 1
db._adapter.FALSE = 0
```

This fixed the issue!

source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/IukqqZF_PPE

This has been moved in recent versions of web2py.

```
db._adapter.dialect.types['boolean'] = 'TINYINT(1)'
db._adapter.dialect.true = 1
db._adapter.dialect.false = 0
```